# The volume bar doesn't work on Windows 10, Lenovo thinkpad L440

Tags: windows-10, audio, thinkpad, speakers

[image]

When I change the volume, it doesn't change the actual volume I hear. Any idea?

Also, other detail, when windows boots with external speakers plugged in, when I plug those speakers out, internal speakers don't output any sound.

Comment: What sound devices do you have? The most logical explanation, that the volume is not being decreased or increased, is you are changing the volume settings on the incorrect sound device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Control Panel, Sounds, Playback tab and set Speakers to default.

Restart, run Lenovo System Updater or Vantage Updater and update all drivers including BIOS.

Do a final restart and set up Speakers again. Start with only the built in speaker and check the volume operation.

You can also check Windows Update, Optional Updates and check for driver updates. Not all Lenovo updates are included.

Open Start, Settings, Update and security and then see if there is an Optional Update link on the right side. If no optional updates are there, then you must install the driver from the Lenovo Site.

Comment: I don't have Lenovo system updater, and I don't really want to install this.

Comment: Go to the Lenovo Support site for your specific model and get System Update. No issue in installing it. Otherwise update all drivers manually (unnecessarily slow way).

Comment: shouldn't windows update do it? I suspect windows update will replace the driver if I install another one.

Comment: Try Windows Update optional devices but that does not do all Lenovo drivers.

Comment: What is "Windows Update optional devices" ? EDIT: oh yeah, found it, but nothing about sound.

Comment: Open Start, Settings, Update and security and then see if there is an Optional Update link on the right side.